# How can give multiple if statements one regrouped output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, printing, pycharm

I would like to know if I can regroup multiple if statements into output, for example:

```
if x == "Hey":
    print("hello")

if x == "Hello":
    print("Hello")`
```

I was wondering if the two if statements would have a shortcut one output (aka print("Hello") in this situation).

Comment: But `x` cannot be `"Hey"` *and* `"Hello"` at the same time, so (given proper indentation) your code seems to work.

Comment: Would something like this work: `if x in {"Hey", "Hello"}: print("Hello")`
PS: you could extract the set to avoid creating it every time you do the check

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` logical operator:

```
if x == 'Hello' or x == 'Hey':
    print('Hello')
```

One alternate way is using `in`:

```
if x in ['Hello', 'Hey']:
    print('Hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator

```
if x in ("Hey","Hello"):
    print("Hello")
```

To reduce case sensitivity:

```
if x.lower() in ("hey","hello"):
    print("Hello")
```

Comment: `casefold()` is recommend for caseless comparison [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)
Also, wouldn't a set or a tuple would be better than a mutable list (first faster, second immutable) ?

Comment: @Sylvaus Ok Thanks! Done ! 